# In H264, what does the field_pic_flag mean and does it have a relation to encoding intervals?

Tags: video, compression, video-streaming, h.264

I am looking at a H264 stream which has all true field_pic_flags in every slice header. The standard says the following about it:

field_pic_flag equal to 1 specifies that the slice is a slice of a coded field. field_pic_flag equal to 0 specifies that the slice is a slice of a coded frame. When field_pic_flag is not present it shall be inferred to be equal to 0.

Can anybody elaborate on what a field_pic_flag signifies, what the difference between a field / frame is, and what the significance of having all field_pic_flags = 1 is?

The video also has a set Encoding Interval / Gov Length: 1 iframe 69 pframes 1 iframe 69 pframes 1 iframe 69 pframes etc etc....
Does the field_pic_flag have any relation to this interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means exactly what is written in spec i.e. specify if is full frame or field. As for difference between frame and field you should read about [interlaced video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video) and [field (video)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28video%29). In short field is half vertical resolution part (only odd or even lines) of full frame. And no field_pic_flag doesn't have anything todo with "intervals". For the note field_pic_flag=1 is only used for encoding interlaced video with PAFF coding (there is also MBAFF coding for interlaced video).

Comment: what flag is used to denote the `mbaff` coding for an interlaced video in h264

Comment: frame_mbs_only_flag = 0 and mb_adaptive_frame_field_flag = 1